# Function that counts the occurrences of an element in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I'm trying to write a function that counts the occurrences of a specific element in an array, specified as a function argument.

Ex: for the array [5,7,12,5,3,3,5], the function countOccurrences(3) would return a value of 2.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Counting the occurrences / frequency of array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667888/counting-the-occurrences-frequency-of-array-elements)

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask], the first section of which is titled "Search, and research". This is a common question that has been asked hundreds of times before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter array and return length:

```js
const arr = [5,7,12,5,3,3,5];

const occurences = (array, el) => {
  return array.filter(a => a === el).length
}

const result = occurences(arr, 3);
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```js
const filter = (arr, val) => {
    return arr.filter(item => item === val).length
}
```