# Find duplicates of an array and replace it with its number

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Say I have an array:

`arr = [25, 25, 25, 20, 15, 10, 10, 5];`

and I want to count up the number of duplicates (ie. three 25s and 2 10s) and make a new array that becomes:

`newArr = ['25 * 3', 20, 15, '10 * 2', 5];`

How should I go about doing this? Thanks!

Comment: Use `reduce` or a for loop?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I think even though he use reduce, he wont be getting the count of the repeated items, right?

Comment: This one has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667888/counting-the-occurrences-frequency-of-array-elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop to iterate through each item of the array, keeping track of how many times each item has been seen before.

**Demo:**

```js
let arr = [25, 25, 25, 20, 15, 10, 10, 5];

let result = [], seenBefore = [];

arr.forEach((item) => {
  let seen = seenBefore.indexOf(item);
  if (seen !== -1) return result[seen].count++;
  result.push({ name: item, count: 1 });
  seenBefore.push(item);
});

result = result.map(({ name, count }) =>
  count > 1 ? `${name} * ${count}` : name
);

console.log(result);
```

**The same technique but smaller using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):**

```js
let arr = [25, 25, 25, 20, 15, 10, 10, 5];

let result = arr
  .reduce(
    (acc, item) => {
      acc[1].indexOf(item) !== -1 ? acc[0][acc[1].indexOf(item)].count++ : (acc[0].push({ name: item, count: 1 }), acc[1].push(item));
      return acc;
    },
    [[], []]
  )[0]
  .map(({ name, count }) => (count > 1 ? `${name} * ${count}` : name));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be solved using Set and filter

```js
let arr = [25, 25, 25, 20, 15, 10, 10, 5];

const newArr = [...new Set(arr)].map((x) => {
    const count = arr.filter(y => y == x).length
    return count > 1 ? x + " * " + count: x;
})

console.log(newArr) //  ["25 * 3", 20, 15, "10 * 2", 5]
```

or if you want the numeric value you can do that

```js
let arr = [25, 25, 25, 20, 15, 10, 10, 5];
    const newArr = [...new Set(arr)].map((x) => arr.filter(y => y == x).length * x)
    console.log(newArr) // [75, 20, 15, 20, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `reduce` and check if the current element in the iteration is equal to the previous element and then also what is the type of last element added to the accumulator.

```js
const arr = [25, 25, 25, 20, 15, 10, 10, 5];
const result = arr.reduce((r, e, i, arr) => {
  if (i && e === arr[i - 1]) {
    if (typeof r[r.length - 1] === 'number') {
      r[r.length - 1] = `${e} * 2`;
    } else {
      const [key, value] = r[r.length - 1].split(' * ')
      r[r.length - 1] = `${key} * ${+value + 1}`
    }
  } else {
    r.push(e)
  }

  return r;
}, [])

console.log(result)
```