# Change value array to string, when array value is determine with specific rule

Tags: javascript, console.log

i want to ask
how do we convert the contents of the array into a string and calculate the same value?

```
ex: 
const arr = [1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3]
```

If arr contain

values 1 = red,

values 2 = white,

values 3 = brown

**I have tried with the if else method but it doesn't work

my expected output was

```
red : 2 white : 2 brown : 4
```

can anyone help me? Thank you in advance

Comment: So you want to count the number of occurrences? If so, see [Counting the occurrences / frequency of array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667888/counting-the-occurrences-frequency-of-array-elements). All that is left is setting the correct label

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: No sir, i want to change arr values to string first and count the same value later
ex: values 1 is red and it was count = 2

Comment: Easier in two steps: `const colors = ["","red","white","brown"];
const count = arr => arr.reduce((prev, curr) => (prev[curr] = ++prev[curr] || 1, prev), {});
const arr = [1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3];
const strings = Object.entries(count(arr)).reduce((acc,[key,val]) => (acc[colors[key]] = val, acc),{});
console.log(strings)
`

Comment: @mplungjan I believe your message is best suited for an answer with code formatting

Comment: @Apolo except I closed the question so I would need to post a jsfiddle

Comment: Oh I missed the fact it was closed, my bad :)

Comment: 1. I closed because it is the same -  you want a frequency 
2. I posted a solution for you too - here is a more readable version: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/tj80nzm7/

Comment: that's not the method I want, what I want is if array contains values 1 then color is red

Comment: That is what my code does. You can even do it in one go: `const colors = ["", "red", "white", "brown"]; const count1 = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => (acc[colors[curr]] = ++acc[colors[curr]], acc), {"red":0, "white":0, "brown":0});`

Comment: Is possible using if else method? If arr contains values 1 is red. because the way you provided it creates a new array.

Comment: If you want to replace the array just do so: `const acc = {"red":0, "white":0, "brown":0};
const colorArr = Object.keys(acc); arr = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => (acc[colorArr[curr-1]]++, acc), acc);` https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/tj80nzm7/

I added a color replace too

`let arr1 = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3];
arr1.forEach((elem,i) => arr1[i] = colors[elem] ); const freq = arr1.reduce((prev, curr) => (prev[curr] = ++prev[curr] || 1, prev), {});`

Comment: I'm sorry I misunderstood your answer sir.  your answer is very usefull and thank you in advance

Comment: @mplungjan how to use divide operation in the code?

if red has a value of 2 divided by 2 = 1

Comment: When and where and for what reason?

Comment: @mplungjan because the color code is used for the variable socks  
and if the color is 2 then it is counted as a pair, if 4 it is worth 2 pairs