# Grouping Data in TypeScript Array

Tags: arrays, typescript, grouping

I have JSON data that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "tags": [
            "Test 1",
            "Test 2",
            "Test 3"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "tags": [
            "Test 2",
            "Test 3",
            "Test 4"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "tags": [
            "Test 3",
            "Test 4"
        ]
    }
]
```

I would like to transform this into data that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Test 1",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "Test 2",
        "count": 2
    },
    {
        "name": "Test 3",
        "count": 3
    },
    {
        "name": "Test 4",
        "count": 1
    }
]
```

I can think of some brute ways to do this, but I'm hoping there is something more performant and a little sexier? Possibly using `.groupBy()` or `.reduce()`?

Thanks for taking the time to check out my question.

Comment: There's nothing no special sexiness for iterating through data structures. What solution do you have that you feel is too brute force?

Answer (score 1):

I would:

- parse the json
- gather all tags in an array
- count occurences using one of the approaches in [Counting the occurrences / frequency of array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667888/counting-the-occurrences-frequency-of-array-elements)

```ts
interface Item {
  id: number,
  tags: string[]
}

function countOccurences(a: string[]) {
  return a.reduce(function (acc: {[key: string]: number}, curr: string) {
    acc[curr] ??= 0;
    acc[curr]++;
    return acc;
  }, {});
}

const data: Item[] = JSON.parse(json);
const tagOccurences = countOccurences(data.flatMap(o => o.tags))
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6#code/MYewdgzgLgBAVhcMC8MAGBtAUDXMDeOexARAJYAmJAXDAIwA0RxuJUAhgOYQ0zYsCYJACoBTaPRJNBLEeNgAmKcxlCxEgMwkVxALoqAvtLyEZ5KrQXGBbLj1r9VrdYuVPn8mFuuq5EgCzaMvrERiqmgua8Gj6kHNy8jk5+sN46kS4wgem4IXgGWLpoANxYZGBQogBOAGbswKIwAJKVALYERJS0YACurQBG1cbxELTQVeWcGPoFWDU9YMBQZEigC1AA8sDAPVWii+IAFOxjUBNgU7oAlB24e1C7YDDsAHR7FD0Nh-OLy0jH21o+AwAGtRABPU7nTi6bp9QZVIwwHZVKpQyY3CK4erADAoqq6GAAfiJqAADKViDi8bsCQBqOmUvD3R7PbZMpH4AxXUqzUCQWAUdgcWgtUStaYoGAAKQAyhsAHIvAAO7CqEFEhwQ4B5WH5EniWxR+waEClawqRt2JqOQo4LxqABthQBZdjKw4gFAAPhgIBeIyuVz14EQjtEL0dIE4h0N22tBwgPKAA)

Answer (score 0):

Using [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) iteration and a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) as a cache is a very straightforward approach... and sexy.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAKghgcwM4HUCWwAWBJAJlAXigG8AoKKNXALigDsBXAWwCMIAnAbnKmESVpJg7NHQQBtALrcAvt1KhIsRAGEA9gzrBCJHgGMNW2o1YduFOnCYRBw0QlnyAZpr3A0aulABuHEAGUIAA8QeAR1TWAOKAAKUTAGYFow1AwcXCkASmTVQ2ApXQoDOiEoJjgwHToIAHcoAFkKgB4hETEAGnpmNnYAPhjM+QonNXZY4tLiPmQZKDUnSjoE4EzCiigRsZiJ7UtrOYXppFWydfXysAA6JAhgGL2ITpiLy4Rb+6sIVYB+b6gABlWAGooABGQY8CgyHjQnjsW4MdhecSXVEvCBaEQQJADSSXC4xGLiB6dAyRSSrAi9WLEElQMlaGSZCGwnZQABWSE8OgABuJiAAiKgC6ig9oCo4i8QCmDY7SggXi2WlABMiplcqgAGYBZIZO1BcLqCrxZLqNLldo1UrNTqbaUACy6-WG3AirWm-hSjWlO0+7ROvWSHncNnxRI5ZDoLB4ApEABS-gA8gA5S5gODsG4xTmeCGkNnwpAMAA22iIvnYAWCoVykQ4cSWiQhEzUJYglxLagQMSLpZWnCAA)

```ts
type TagsWithId = {
  id: number;
  tags: string[];
};

type TagCount = {
  count: number;
  name: string;
};

function verySexyTagCounter (input: TagsWithId[]): TagCount[] {
  const map = new Map<string, number>();

  for (const {tags} of input) {
    for (const name of tags) {
      map.set(name, (map.get(name) ?? 0) + 1);
    }
  }

  return [...map.entries()].map(([name, count]) => ({name, count}));
}

const json = `[{"id":1,"tags":["Test 1","Test 2","Test 3"]},{"id":2,"tags":["Test 2","Test 3","Test 4"]},{"id":3,"tags":["Test 3","Test 4"]}]`;
const input: TagsWithId[] = JSON.parse(json);

const result = verySexyTagCounter(input);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` inside `reduce` to group the tags.

```js
const array = [{
    id: 1,
    tags: ['Test 1', 'Test 2', 'Test 3'],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    tags: ['Test 2', 'Test 3', 'Test 4'],
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    tags: ['Test 3', 'Test 4'],
  },
];

const frequencies = Object.values(array.reduce((acc, curr) =>
  curr.tags.reduce(
    (nAcc, tag) => ((nAcc[tag] ??= {name: tag,count: 0}),nAcc[tag].count++,nAcc),
    acc
  ), {}
));
console.log(frequencies);
```

---

In TypeScript:

```
const array = [{
    id: 1,
    tags: ['Test 1', 'Test 2', 'Test 3'],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    tags: ['Test 2', 'Test 3', 'Test 4'],
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    tags: ['Test 3', 'Test 4'],
  },
];

type Frequency = {
    name: string,
    count: number
}

const frequencies = Object.values(array.reduce((acc, curr) =>
  curr.tags.reduce(
    (nAcc, tag) => ((nAcc[tag] ??= {name: tag,count: 0}),nAcc[tag].count++,nAcc),
    acc
  ), {} as Record<string, Frequency>
));
console.log(frequencies);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwXAnjAvDA2gbwFAyEwCWAJgFwwCMANAUVHAOYSVYDkAKgKbTXs0YXXrABMAoTz4BmdgF06hAL6KY%20IiQoxRqwoxZthfcYKOxZpqbAAs81SvrqiZStN0x9rbGZgXJImFsFegc5AG48PCgUAAduGAAxBG4ARwBXbjBgNEwnQjA4AFtuSmgEYjAmd1A0sChKMDTCgCNuBDwlSNBIWAAzZPTM4GJeDBgAeWaAK25gKAA6ADc4ABsMiAAKRGQUeeTSNOBuDa3gYEFgNKQASgwAPnpLpHnPPe4Do436Qg2wAEEzoJ9Ld0HcYCd-mcsPo5DAAPxw3IFYqUfQ0Gp1SgABiU1xokOA0OYcnmGKgAGpyfiAcA8d94Gd6Hi1Ep4BAYAAlWYgBCkAA8ZQqVUSAwyWRQD2u1wi3QgIBW3HmKxATA2-VSYuGvGlQA)