# how to remove same elements from array and add count to other objects javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 1 object (it came from localstroage). But there are some dublicates. how can i remove it from easy way?

"mainchart" is my array object.

```
function check() {
  for (let i1 = 0; i1 < mainchart.length; i1++) {
    for (let i2 = 0; i2 < mainchart.length; i2++) {  
      if (mainchart[i1].id === mainchart[i2].id) {
        console.log(mainchart[i1] , mainchart[i2]);
      }
    }
  }
}

check();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Counting the occurrences / frequency of array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667888/counting-the-occurrences-frequency-of-array-elements)

Comment: it helped me thanks. but how can i count removed elements?

Comment: becouse i create shoping basket with js:)

Comment: My link contains multiple solutions to count the elements.

Comment: do you use discord? can you help me from there?

Comment: No, sorry. I can help you here. Ask a specfic question.

Comment: thankssss a lot for your help

Answer (score -2, accepted):

An easy way to remove duplicate values from an array is converting the array in to a set (collection of unique values), putting the values of the set in a new array:

```
let array1 = ["a", "b", true, 3, 67, true, "a"];

let array2 = [...new Set(array1)];

console.log(array2); // [ 'a', 'b', true, 3, 67 ]
```

Hope it can help you

Comment: _"how to remove same elements from array and add **count to other objects** javascript?"_ Where do you count? Your code doesn't work with objects, only with primitives.

Comment: i want to know how many element get removed