# How to count strings in array using only reduce, when some strings might also need splitting first

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, count

I have an array with strings that I want to count:

```js
const myArr = ["a, b, c", "a", "b", "a, b", "b", "a", "a", "a, b, c, d"]
```

I want to get a count for how many `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` in `myArr`.

Seeing answers from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667888/counting-the-occurrences-frequency-of-array-elements), *I could* use array methods, `map()`, `split()`, `flat()` then `reduce()`:

```js
const res = myArr.map((x) => x.split(", ")).flat().reduce((acc, x) => {
    return acc[x] ? ++acc[x] : (acc[x] = 1), acc;
  }, {});

console.log(res)
// { a: 6, b: 5, c: 2, d: 1 }
```

Although the above code gives the desired output, I want to do everything within **one** run of `reduce()`. Is it possible?

I've tried something out, but still don't know how I could complete it:

```js
const res2 = myArr.reduce((acc, x) => {
  acc.push(x.split(", "));
  return acc.flat();
}, []);

console.log(res2)
// [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ]
//                  ^^^^^^^^^^ obviously not what I want!
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Counting the occurrences / frequency of array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667888/counting-the-occurrences-frequency-of-array-elements)

Comment: You just have to move the operations done in your map into the reduce, but the efficiency is the same

Comment: @pilchard, regarding your 1st comment -- I have indeed referenced to that post. Regarding your 2nd comment, I'm not sure what the right implementation within `reduce` is . My goal is to get the count using one call to `reduce`, regardless of what's going on inside the reducer function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply move the [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) into the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method.

```js
const myArr = ["a, b, c", "a", "b", "a, b", "b", "a", "a", "a, b, c, d"];

const result = myArr.reduce((acc, str) => {
  const chars = str.split(', ');

  for(const x of chars) {
    acc[x] ??= 0;
    acc[x]++;
  }
  
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate the values inside each split value from `myArr` to update the accumulator:

```js
const myArr = ["a, b, c", "a", "b", "a, b", "b", "a", "a", "a, b, c, d"]

const res = myArr.reduce((acc, x) => {
  x.split(', ').forEach(v => acc[v] = (acc[v] || 0) + 1);
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an one-line version:

```js
const myArr = ["a, b, c", "a", "b", "a, b", "b", "a", "a", "a, b, c, d"]

const out = myArr.reduce((o, s) => (s.split(", ").forEach(i => o[i]++ || (o[i] = 1)), o), {});

console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

First you split it up by comma and do an flatMap.

After this, you map it again to trim the whitespace.

After this, you can start to count it:

```js
const myArr = ["a, b, c", "a", "b", "a, b", "b", "a", "a", "a, b, c, d"]

let result = myArr.flatMap(c => c.split(","))
                  .map(c => c.trim())
                  .reduce((prev, curr) => {
                     if(prev[curr]) prev[curr]++
                     if(!prev[curr]) prev[curr] = 1;
                     return prev
                  }, {})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I'm explicitly looking to avoid operations external to `reduce`. In fact, that is the point of the posted question.