# Count the number of ocurrences of a duplicated value in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array:
[image: array]

In this array I have at least 3x 'a' or 2x 'c'. Is it possible to get the number of times that a character is duplicated?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I have. But I'm only able to get the characters in each array, not in all of them.

Comment: You can flatten your array with `myArray.flat()` and then use your approach :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Counting the occurrences / frequency of array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667888/counting-the-occurrences-frequency-of-array-elements) And use flat() as @RoboRobok suggested.

Comment: "count the number of occurrences" is probably a more appropriate description of what you are trying to do than "length of a duplicated value"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
const myArray = [
  ["a", "b", "c"],
  ["a", "n", "c"],
  ["e", "f", "g"],
  ["i", "a", "l"],
];
const occurrences = myArray.reduce((count, currentValue) => {
  currentValue.forEach((value) => {
    count[value] ? ++count[value] : (count[value] = 1);
  });
  return count;
}, {});

console.log(JSON.stringify(occurrences));
```

```css
/* StackOverflow snippet: console should overlap rendered HTML area */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Strictly speaking the above counts the occurrences of a letter but if you use `count[value] = 0` instead of `count[value] = 1` it will count the number of duplicates.

Another approach is to flatten the array first using [`flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) and then use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the same way as used above. Again if you set `count[value] = 0` you will count the duplicates, not occurrences, but essentially that's the same thing.

```js
const myArray = [
  ["a", "b", "c"],
  ["a", "n", "c"],
  ["e", "f", "g"],
  ["i", "a", "l"],
];
const occurrences = myArray
  .flat()
  .reduce(
    (count, value) => (
      count[value] ? ++count[value] : (count[value] = 1), count
    ),
    {}
  );

console.log(JSON.stringify(occurrences));
```

```css
/* StackOverflow snippet: console should overlap rendered HTML area */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```