# Count exact occurrences of a certain number in array and return either True or False

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have two arrays

```
Array1 = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3] 
Array2 =[1,1,2,1]
```

Comparing both of the arrays should return result as True as there are same number of occurrences of Integer 1.

```
Array2 = [1,1,2]  //Should return False.
```

In the above case, the result should be false as the no. Of occurrences of 1 or 2 in Array2 don't match with the no. Of occurrences of 1 and 2 in Array1.

```
Array2 = [1,1,2,3,1] //should return True.
```

I tried this but doesn't work for other instances.

```
function allElementsPresent(first, second) {
  return second.every((element) => first.includes(element));
}
```

Thanks in advance! Cheers

Comment: You mean the number of occurrences must match? Please make the criteria for returning true clear.

Comment: @Unmitigated yes right.. Number of occurrences

Comment: @MisterJojo actually I push the second array on click of button.. So there can be another array containing 2's or 3's.. But the first array Is already present with Me.. So just comparing the occurrences if they match or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I understand what you want to accomplish. You want to see if the number of occurrences in the second array matches the first. If that's the case, I've used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5668029/19655730) as a basis

```js
function allElementsPresent(first, second, matchAll = false) {
  if (first.length > 0 && second.length === 0) return false;
  var counts1st = {};
  var counts2nd = {};

  for (var num of first) {
    counts1st[num] = counts1st[num] ? counts1st[num] + 1 : 1;
  }
  for (var num of second) {
    counts2nd[num] = counts2nd[num] ? counts2nd[num] + 1 : 1;
  }

  for (var count in counts2nd) {
    if (matchAll && (!counts1st[count] || counts1st[count] !== counts2nd[count])) return false;
    if (!matchAll && (counts1st[count] && counts1st[count] === counts2nd[count])) return true;
  }
  return matchAll ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: This is how I wanted! Thankss.. Although for blank array it return True..

Comment: Updated: now it will only return true if they're both blank.

Comment: Hi.. Just another doubt if the second array contains 1,1,2,1,1,1..it should still return True as 5 1s are there but it's returning false

Comment: It returns false because the number of **2**s don't match. Are you only concerned with **1**s?

Comment: No I am concerned with occurrences.. If 1 has 5 occurrences in any order it should return True same goes with the 2.. If there are 4 2s then True else false.. Like [1,1,2,1,1,1] should return True and also [1,1,2,1,2,1, 1,2,2] should return True rest cases false

Comment: Do you want it to return true if **any** occurrence count matches, not necessarily all of them?

Comment: Yeah right.. It should check for occurrences simultaneously

Comment: I've added a parameter that makes checking all occurrences optional. If I understand correctly, the default `false` behavior is the one you want.

Comment: For which case would it return false?Actually it's returning True even if the second array has 1 occurrence of 1

Comment: My mistake, fixed an operator on the `!matchAll` line: `||` changed to `&&`

Answer (score 0):

First conditional expression should be checking length

```js
if (first.length != second.length) {
  // They don't have the same number of element thus we don't need to check further
  return -1
}
```

Then, try re-arranging the array in order.
using an ordering algorithm

Then with two loop check if each element of the same index matches each array like below

```js
for(int i =0;i<length;i++)
{
  if (first[i] != second[i]) {
    //if they don't at this instance both array does not have all elements
    return -1;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

simple JS-magic, (if I understand the problem):

```
String(first).includes(second) && // second in first
/[^1,]/.test(second) // not all 1s or empty
```

Sometimes dynamic types really simplify things by treating data generically; use that strength where you can.

If the second array is not allowed to be uniform elements, but could be all non-1 digits, then it's more complicated:

```
String(first).includes(second) && // second in first
RegExp(`[^${second[0]},]`).test(second) // not all uniform or empty
```

as a function:

```
function allElementsPresent(first, second) {  
  return String(first).includes(second) && /[^1,]/.test(second)
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide a snippet of sorts..

Comment: sure, all you have to do is wrap the function boilerplate around it.