# How to count array elements by each element in javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to count Matching values in Array of Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228362/how-to-count-matching-values-in-array-of-javascript)

I have array with elements as,

array_elements = ["2","1","2","2","3","4","3","3","3","5"];

i want to count array elements like following manner,

Answer:

2 comes --> 3 times
 1 comes --> 1 times
 3 comes --> 4 times
 4 comes --> 1 times
 5 comes --> 1 times

**Note : Each value count should print only once.**

Comment: You want them counted in Ruby or JavaScipt? If the latter, why ruby tags?

Comment: Do you know how to write a for loop and use an object. Seems like basic homework 101 type of question.

Comment: duplicate questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840781/easiest-way-to-find-duplicate-values-in-a-javascript-array and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228362/how-to-count-matching-values-in-array-of-javascript

Comment: for people who like fancy words, this is a [histogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can sort the elements and loop through them:

```
array_elements = ["2", "1", "2", "2", "3", "4", "3", "3", "3", "5"];

array_elements.sort();

var current = null;
var cnt = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < array_elements.length; i++) {
    if (array_elements[i] != current) {
        if (cnt > 0) {
            document.write(current + ' comes --> ' + cnt + ' times<br>');
        }
        current = array_elements[i];
        cnt = 1;
    } else {
        cnt++;
    }
}
if (cnt > 0) {
    document.write(current + ' comes --> ' + cnt + ' times');
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/aQsuP/

Answer (score 21):

```
var counts = {};

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    counts[array[i]] = (counts[array[i]] + 1) || 1;


console.log(counts);
```

This assumes a `toString` representation of the items in the Array will be acceptable. For example, it will see `1` as being the same as `"1"`.

Given your example Array, this will not be an issue.

Answer (score 5):

```
var array_elements = ["2","1","2","2","3","4","3","3","3","5"];

var result = array_elements.reduce(function(p, c){
    if (c in p) {
       p[c]++;
    } else {
       p[c]=1;
    }
    return p;
}, {});

​console.log(result);​
```

***[The live demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/ak69f/)***

*note: reduce need a shim for old browsers.*

Answer (score 2):

```
var arr = ["2","1","2","2","3","4","3","3","3","5"];
var k = {};

//push into hashtable
for(i in arr){
 k[arr[i]]=(k[arr[i]]||0)+1; //increments count if element already exists
}

//result
for(var j in k) {
 console.log(j+" comes -> "+k[j]+" times");
}
```