# how many times is String X in Array Y

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an array form a sheet looking like [X]:

```
Sat Mar 18 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (MEZ), Sat Mar 11 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (MEZ), Sat Mar 18 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (MEZ), , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,
```

And a date looks like [Y]:

```
Sat Mar 18 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100
```

How can i count the amount of Y in X?

The outcome should look like this:

```
var amountOfYinX = 2;
```

Comment: You are asking how to count duplicates in a JavaScript array.  Which has already been asked:  [Link to Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395257/how-to-count-duplicate-value-in-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count duplicate value in an array in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395257/how-to-count-duplicate-value-in-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: @SandyGood its nearly the same but to much and i can´t figure out how to splitt the code right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the information that you have given, this works:

```
function countDupsInArray() {
  var amountOfYinX,data,i,L;

  data = ["Sat Mar 18 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (MEZ)", "Sat Mar 11 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (MEZ)", "Sat Mar 18 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (MEZ)", , , , , ];

  amountOfYinX = 0;
  L = data.length;

  for (i=0;i<L;i++) {
    if (data[i] === "Sat Mar 18 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (MEZ)") {
      amountOfYinX++;
    }
  }

  Logger.log('amountOfYinX: ' + amountOfYinX)
  return amountOfYinX;
};
```

Comment: i tried to change the hardcoded date in the for loop generated date, but it won´t work
'  var date = new Date();
  var dateString = date.toString();'