# javascript counting duplicates in array

Tags: javascript

Please consider this JS function

I have seen this [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395257/how-to-count-duplicate-value-in-an-array-in-javascript) question but couldn't understand.

```
function a (ResultArray){
    var counts={};
    for ( p = 0; p < ResultArray.length; p++){            
        counts[ResultArray[p]] = (counts[ResultArray[p]] + 1) || 1;            
    }
    return counts;
}

var arr = ["a","b","c","d","a","b","e"];        
var res = new a(arr);
console.log(res)
```

Its working fine and giving the count. I need to understand  how is it giving the count, specially `(counts[ResultArray[p]] + 1) || 1;` part. what is `+1` and `||` doing.

Comment: It looks like it's attempting to increment the value for a particular key, then if that fails (because the key doesn't exist), it sets it to `1`. --- Honestly, it's a pretty strange looking line of code.

Comment: `+ 1` is adding 1 to `counts[ResultArray[p]]` and `||` is a truthy check: if `counts[ResultArray[p]] + 1` is `NaN, undefined, null, or 0` the expression will evaluate to `1` see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476436/is-there-a-null-coalescing-operator-in-javascript) post for greater detail

Comment: @Patrick Barr , thats what I am trying to understand , what is it achieving by adding 1, or what is it checking by adding 1. Is it checking the next value? If it is , then how is it keeping track of previously found values and then incrementing them. Its too confusing for me

Comment: array.length-(new Set(array)).length would work too...

Comment: @user1207289 It's keeping track of how many times something appears in the array with an object who's keys are the values in the array, so it's just adding 1 to the count of that value, and at the end the object will have the counts of each duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the main confusion comes from this line:

```
counts[ResultArray[p]] = (counts[ResultArray[p]] + 1) || 1;
```

The `||` operator returns what is on the left side if it is "truthy" (anything other than the "falsy" values `false`, `0`, `''`, `null`, `undefined`, and `NaN`), otherwise it returns what is on the right hand side.

If `ResultArray[p]` is not inside of `counts`, then `counts[ResultArray[p]]` will be `undefined`. Since `undefined + 1` is `NaN`, the left hand side of `||` is "falsy", so it will return the right hand side `1`.

Otherwise, `counts[ResultArray[p]]` will be the amount of times we've already seen `ResultArray[p]`, and we'll add `1` to it. In this case the left hand side will be "truthy" and it will return the new count.

Comment: I am even more confused 1) how come `counts[ResultArray[p]]` is amount of times and not `"a"` when  this   `var counts={};counts["a"]=1;counts["b"]=2;console.log(counts["a"]);` prints `1`. 
 2) lets say , I understand the issue in 1 , when `ResultArray[p]` is not in `counts` and it returns `1`,  does that mean it increments by `1` or that iteration is not counted.

Comment: Please disregard 1) above, I understand that `counts[ResultArray[p]]` is the value of `"a"` and not `"a"`

Comment: @user1207289 Suppose `ResultArray[p]` is `"a"`, and `"a"` is not in `counts`. Then `counts[ResultArray[p]] = (counts[ResultArray[p]] + 1) || 1` is the same as `counts["a"] = (counts["a"] + 1) || 1`, which is the same as `counts["a"] = (undefined + 1) || 1`, which is the same as `counts["a"] = NaN || 1`, which finally is the same as `counts["a"] = 1`. That is, the first time we encounter `"a"`, we set `counts["a"]` to `1`.

Comment: I think reading it this way makes it better for me to understand, just sharing it here, in case anyone needs it. when an element is encountered,the particular line in question is evaluated as `value of key  = (previous value of key +1) || 1`  and since for each key value is `undefined` when the key is encountered first time the line is evaluated as `value of key  = (undefined +1) || 1`

Answer (score 1):

The array value hasn't been set yet, so you can't increment undefined. The first time it hits a value, the "|| 1" portion sets the initial value to 1. If it hits that same index again (which is no longer undefined and now set to 1), it executes the left side instead and increments the pre-existing value by 1.

Comment: When I read this answer now, after above explanation, it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

there are some things to keep in mind in the above algorithm

1. javascript objects are represented by sets, dictionary hence `counts = {}` is just a set or dict hence `counts."a"` or `counts.a` or `counts[a]` can all be used to access the value inside of `counts` object therefore `counts.a = 1` or `counts["a"] = null` is an assignment to counts set (object).
2. javascript dynamically allocates variables hence `counts[ResultArray[p]] since`counts`is a object javascript dynamically creates the value of`
   ResultArray[p]]`as a property or key to`counts` as javascript is loosely typed
3. evaluations start from left to right on the line 
   `counts[ResultArray[p]] = (counts[ResultArray[p]] + 1) || 1;`
   javascript start evaluating starting from `count[ResultArray[p]]` where 
   `counts` evaluates to an object (set, dictionary) then it moves to `ResultArray` which evaluates to array during runtime `p` is then evaluated to a number say 0 in first iteration hence the whole evaluation is `counts[ResultArray[0]]` where javascript creates the key `counts.a` or `counts."a"` and assigns to it undefined evaluation then continues to
   `(counts[ResultArray[p]] + 1)` || 1; and inside of it `counts[ResultArray[p]]` since it had already done in previous step that evaluates to `counts.a` or `counts."a"` = undefined then moves to `undefined +` this should look like this after left right evaluation `(undefined + 1)` 
   javascript then evaluates that to `NaN` in the next step of evaluation
   '(NaN)`|| 1  where`NaN`is always false but 1 is always true in javascript and true = 1 false = 0 hence 1 is assigned to`counts.a`or`counts."a" or `counts[a]` = 1

here is javascript evaluation steps from left to right broken down
`counts[ResultArray[p]] = (counts[ResultArray[p]] + 1) || 1;`

1. `counts = {}` (object,set or dict) in javascript
2. `ResultArray`  (array)
3. `p`            (integer)
4. `ResultArray[p] = "a"` in first iteration
5. `counts["a"]`    (undefined is assigned since there was no previous assignement)
6. =              (assignment operator)
7. `counts = {}` (object,set or dict) in javascript
8. `ResultArray`  (array)
9. `p`            (integer)
10. `ResultArray[p] = "a"` in first iteration
11. `counts["a"]`    (undefined)
12. `+`             (addition operation)
13. `1`            (integer)
14. `counts["a"] + 1 = undefined + 1 = NaN`
15. `NaN || 1` = 1 (boolean 1 = true false = 0 Nan = 0 = false 0 || 1  1 wins in or statement)
16. counts["a"] = 0 || 1  (1 is assigned to counts["a"])