# Convert array to sub arrays based on their count in JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sub-array

How can I convert my array to sub arrays depending upon their elements values counts in JavaScript or jQuery?

For example:

```
var myArray=["a","b","c","a","a","c","b"];
```

Expected output after counting the elements a, b and c

```
outputArray=[["a",3],["b",2],["c",2]];
```

Comment: Why sub arrays like that? Why not something like `[{letter: "a", count: 3}, {letter: "b"...} ...]`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count duplicate value in an array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395257/how-to-count-duplicate-value-in-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: no it is not duplicate in above question array is not converting into sub arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `reduce()` and ES6 `Map()` and spread syntax `...`.

```js
var myArray=["a","b","c","a","a","c","b"];

var result = [...myArray.reduce(function(r, e) {
  return r.set(e, !r.get(e) ? 1 : r.get(e) + 1)
}, new Map())]

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Nice!!, seen as your using ES6, an arrow function would make it look even nicer.  `var result = [...myArray.reduce((r, e) => r.set(e, !r.get(e) ? 1 : r.get(e) + 1), new Map())]`

Comment: thanks it works perfectly @nenad

Answer (score 0):

If you want solution in your way than try it

```js
var myArray=["a","b","c","a","a","c","b"];
var obj = [];
for (var i = 0, j = myArray.length; i < j; i++) {
   obj[myArray[i]] = (obj[myArray[i]] || 0) + 1;
}
var finalArr = [];
for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var arr = [];
        arr.push(key);
        arr.push(obj[key]);
        finalArr.push(arr);
    }
}
console.log(finalArr);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function countLetters(arr) {
    return arr.reduce(function(r, e) {
        r[e] = (r[e] || 0) + 1;
        return r;
    }, {});
}
```

An alternative method

Comment: You should answer the question the way the user wants and then give your input and alternative method after. I didn't down vote but most likely whomever did, that is why.