# Javascript - Counting duplicates in array of object with many fields in es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have object array like this.

```
const array = [ { x: 1, y: 2 }, { x: 3, y: 4 }, { x: 1, y: 2 }, { x: 3, y: 4 }, { x: 1, y: 2 }, { x: 3, y: 12 } ]
```

I want to count duplicates objects and store the count as new object field.

I found this snippet and it work great but it not exactly what i need.

```
const names = [{  _id: 1 }, { _id: 1}, { _id: 2}, { _id: 1}]

    const result = [...names.reduce( (mp, o) => {
    if (!mp.has(o._id)) mp.set(o._id, Object.assign({ count: 0 }, o));
    mp.get(o._id).count++;
    return mp;
    }, new Map).values()];

    console.log(result);
```

It works with object with one field _id. In my case there are two, x and y

How should I modify that code?

In brief...I would like to receive the result:

```
result = [ { x: 1, y: 2, count:3 }, { x: 3, y: 4, count:2 }, { x: 3, y: 12, count:1 } ]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count duplicate value in an array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395257/how-to-count-duplicate-value-in-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: You can use `JSON.stringify([o.x, o.y])` or `o.x+'|'+o.y` instead of `o._id` - anything that uniquely identifies your objects and fits your data types

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Object.values()` and `reduce()` methods to return new array of objects.

```js
const array = [ { x: 1, y: 2 }, { x: 3, y: 4 }, { x: 1, y: 2 }, { x: 3, y: 4 }, { x: 1, y: 2 }, { x: 3, y: 12 } ]

const result = Object.values(array.reduce((r, e) => {
  let k = `${e.x}|${e.y}`;
  if(!r[k]) r[k] = {...e, count: 1}
  else r[k].count += 1;
  return r;
}, {}))

console.log(result)
```

Here is the solution with `Map` and spread syntax `...`

```js
const array = [ { x: 1, y: 2 }, { x: 3, y: 4 }, { x: 1, y: 2 }, { x: 3, y: 4 }, { x: 1, y: 2 }, { x: 3, y: 12 } ]

const result = [...array.reduce((r, e) => {
  let k = `${e.x}|${e.y}`;
  if(!r.has(k)) r.set(k, {...e, count: 1})
  else r.get(k).count++
  return r;
}, new Map).values()]

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thank you! it's exactly what i needed

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it would be to create an index mapping both x and y to the result entry:

```js
let index = { };
let result = [ ];
const array = [ { x: 1, y: 2 }, { x: 3, y: 4 }, { x: 1, y: 2 }, { x: 3, y: 4 }, { x: 1, y: 2 }, { x: 3, y: 12 } ];
array.forEach(point => {
    let key = '' + point.x + '||' + point.y;
    if (key in index) {
        index[key].count++;
    } else {
        let newEntry = { x: point.x, y: point.y, count: 1 };
        index[key] = newEntry;
        result.push(newEntry);
    }
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: can i use conditions `in` to count the values of object like this 
```let data = [{
    no: 3,
    name: 'drink'
  },
  {
    no: 90,
    name: 'eat'
  },
  {
    no: 20,
    name: 'swim'
  }
];```