# to filter data from array and group it in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, typescript, sharepoint

i have an array like given below

```
OStatus=["hold","approved","rejected","hold","approved","rejected","hold","approved"]
```

i want something like this in result

```
Oinfo=["hold":3,"approved":3,"rejected":2].
```

Comment: Well what you want is not possible, it would have to be an object

Comment: So what did you try, it is a simple looping problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395257/how-to-count-duplicate-value-in-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: Possible use case for reduce.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: is it possible to get the count of each types? something like this oinfo[3,3,2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you'd like to produce an object which maps keys which are elements from an input array to values which are the counts of each element, you could use Array.reduce, like so:

```
Oinfo = OStatus.reduce((acc, x) => ({ ...acc, [x]: (acc[x] || 0) + 1 }), {})
```

Comment: is it possible to get the count of each types? something like this oinfo[3,3,2]

Comment: Given that `OStatus` equals `["hold","approved","rejected","hold","approved","rejected","hold","approved"]`, then my code produces `{"hold":3,"approved":3,"rejected":2}`. Is that what you want?