# Count of values in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, count

I have homework to write a function that will be called with 2 parameters:

`a` is a list of numbers.
`amount` represents the count of the numbers in the array.

The function should return the number in the list that occurs `amount` times.

For example , if `a = [5,5,5,3,2,1,1]`, and `amount = 2`, the function should return `1`, because there are only two ones in the array. If `amount = 3`, the function should return `5` , if `amount = 6`, the function will return `0` since there are numbers that occur six time.

Comment: is it sum or count?

Comment: What have you tried? You're not putting any effort into this.

Comment: Please share what you have tried as asking to code from scratch is not suitable on this site.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Assignments aren't usually arbitrary; your instructor, tutorial, or course will have covered the necessary topics to make it possible for you to do this. **Review your course materials, class notes, etc.,** and give it a try. *If* you run into a *specific* problem, research it thoroughly, [search thoroughly here](/help/searching), and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. People will be glad to help.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18242/what-is-the-policy-here-on-homework

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count duplicate value in an array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395257/how-to-count-duplicate-value-in-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: hey sorry guys,this is what I tried so far:
    uniqueCount = ["a","b","c","d","d","e","a","b","c","f","g","h","h","h","e","a"];
    var  count = {};
    uniqueCount.forEach(function(i) { count[i] = (count[i]||0) + 1;});
    console.log(count)
but he said its not valid because he wants it with the "amount" function and I have zero clues

Comment: You can edit the question @DaniTsez to include your code. If you indent the code 4 spaces (or select it and type command-k) it will format it as code.

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```js
var max=3;
var array=[5,5,5,3,2,1,1];
console.log(verify(array,max))
function verify(array,max) {
  var match=0;
     array.map(obj => {
    if(array.filter(x => x === obj).length == max)
      match= obj;
    });
    return match;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to get the values by count using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Since there may be more than one element matching the count, or even 0, an array is returned.

`reduce` is used to build a map (object) of the unique items to their counts. We the find the map entries where the counts match, and the keys (unique items) for these entries are returned.

```js
const count = (arr, num) => {
  const count = arr.reduce((count, x) => {
    count[x] = (count[x] || 0) + 1;
    return count;
  }, {});
  return Object.entries(count)
    .filter(([k, v]) => v === num)
    .map(([k, v]) => +k);
}

console.log(count([5,5,5,3,2,1,1], 1)); // [2, 3]
console.log(count([5,5,5,3,2,1,1], 3)); // [5]
console.log(count([5,5,5,3,2,1,1], 5)); // []
```

Answer (score 0):

make a array of unique values from real `array`. Then loop though it and `filter()` real array to check the count of elements.

```js
const array = [5,5,5,3,2,1,1]
function count(arr,amount){
  const unique = [...new Set(arr)];
  
  for(let item of unique){
    if(arr.filter(num => num === item).length === amount)
      return item;
  }
  return 0;
}
console.log(count(array,1));
console.log(count(array,2));
console.log(count(array,3));
console.log(count(array,4));
console.log(count(array,5));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use below code.
@RaviTeja's code is giving max number of array but **you dont want it**. You want to number which is same quantity with your **"amount" parameter**.This code provides this for you

```
function findingAmount() {  
  var numberContainer = [ 2, 3, 2,5,2,3 ];  
  console.log(findingAmountImp(numberContainer,1)); // result 5
  console.log(findingAmountImp(numberContainer,2)); // result 3
  console.log(findingAmountImp(numberContainer,3)); // result 2
}


function findingAmountImp(numbers,amount) {
var count=1;
  for (i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
       for (j=0; j<numbers.length; j++) {
       if(i===j){
           j=j+1;
           if(j<numbers.length){
                if(numbers[i]  === numbers[j])
                {
                    count++; 
                } 
            }else{
                for(k=0;k<i;k++){
                   if(numbers[i]  === numbers[k])
                    {
                        count++; 
                    } 
                }
            }
       }else{
           if(numbers[i]  === numbers[j])
                {
                    count++; 
                } 
       }
   }
   if( count === amount){

       return numbers[i]
   }  
   count=1;
  }
}
```