# How to append array values in an object as property and value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Go through the array numbers and put each number (2, 4, 5, 37, 0) as a property of the object numbers_duplicates. The value of each property should be that number multiplied by two. (first create the empty object before starting to add the properties and values).

```
var numbers= [2, 4, 5, 37, 0]
var duplicate_numbers = {}
```

// later it should be like this { 0: 0, 2: 4, 4: 8, 5: 10, 37: 74}

```
enter code here for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; ++i) {
duplicate_numbers.push( numbers[i]*2 );
    duplicate_numbers.push( i );}
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count duplicate value in an array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395257/how-to-count-duplicate-value-in-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Here you go mate!

```js
    let arr = [2, 4, 5, 37, 0];
    let obj = {};

    arr.forEach((x) => {
       obj[x] = x*2
    });
    
    console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

For get or set an object property, you can use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation). Here is a version using the basic `for` loop you have written.

```js
var numbers = [2, 4, 5, 37, 0];
var duplicate_numbers = {};

for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
{
    duplicate_numbers[numbers[i]] = numbers[i] * 2;
}

console.log(duplicate_numbers);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Alternatively, you can also use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) in this way:

```js
var numbers = [2, 4, 5, 37, 0];

var duplicate_numbers = numbers.reduce((acc, n) => (acc[n] = 2 * n, acc), {});

console.log(duplicate_numbers);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Object to do this, a object is made of key, value pairs.

```
const numbers_duplicates = {};
const numbers =  [2, 4, 5, 37, 0];

numbers.forEach(number => { numbers_duplicates[number] = number * 2 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const numbers = [2, 4, 5, 37, 0] ;
const duplicateNumbers = {};
const numbersSorted = numbers.sort((a, b) => a - b);

for (let i = 0; i < numbersSorted.length; i++) {
  duplicateNumbers[numbersSorted[i]] = numbersSorted[i] * 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider a Map. This is a special object exactly made for purposes that you need.
It has a bunch of arraylike methods for handling that kind of objects.
Please take a look [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

```
var numbers= [2, 4, 5, 37, 0];
var duplicate_numbers = new Map();
numbers.forEach((val)=> {
    duplicate_numbers.set(val, val*2);
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var numbers = [2, 4, 5, 37, 0];
var duplicate_numbers = {};

var result = numbers.forEach(num => {
  duplicate_numbers[num] = num * 2
});

console.log(duplicate_numbers);
```

Comment: `map` will always return a new array. The OP wants an object.

Comment: updated the answer, please check now.. i miss understood the question

Comment: What if num is zero?

Comment: I think my answer is perfectly working accordin to the question, not sure why it's marked negative