# Find int that appears an odd number of times in an array

Tags: javascript

I am working on this task where I need to find a number that happens to appear an odd number of times in an array.

I believe I've almost done it, but if some number appears more than once in a row (like `1` in `[1,1,3,1,1]`), it will always return that number, no matter if it appears an odd number of times or not.

```js
function findOdd(A) {
  var a;
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    a = A[i];
    for (var l = i + 1; l < A.length; l++) {
      if (a == A[l]) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    if (!(count % 2)) {
      break;
    } else {
      count = 0;
    }
  }
  return a;
}

console.log(findOdd([ 1, 1, 2, -2, 5, 2, 4, 4, -1, -2, 5 ]));
```

I've tried to play with adding 1 to count if [i] = [i+1], but it didn't work.

I'd expect output of `findOdd([1, 1, 2, -2, 5, 2, 4, 4, -1, -2, 5])` to be `-1`, but it is `1`. The function always returns first number that happens to be equal to next element of an array.

Comment: @NinaScholz Maybe i misunderstood, but it cant be a negative number, my output should be not count, but integer that appears an odd number of times, so count is always positive

Comment: The way you are counting is broken. When you get to the second `1` you count how many ones are after that, which is zero. So your algorithm thinks it only occurs once – an odd number of times. To do this the way you are doing it, you need to loop through the whole array in both loops.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count duplicate value in an array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395257/how-to-count-duplicate-value-in-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works but I wonder how the performance compares to simply doing for loops. The complexity seems to be the same.

```js
function findOdd(a) {
  let m = {};

  a.forEach(e => (m[e] in m) ? m[e] += 1 : m[e] = 1);
  for (k in m) {
    if (m[k] % 2 != 0) return k;
  }
}

console.log(findOdd([1, 1, 3, 1, 1]));
console.log(findOdd([1, 1, 2, -2, 5, 2, 4, 4, -1, -2, 5]));
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to reset count or use a break.

```
function findOdd(A) {
    for (var i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
        var count = 0;
        for (var l = 0; l < A.length; l++) {
            if (A[i] === A[l]) count++;
        }
        if (count % 2 !== 0) return A[i];
    }
}
```

An important thing to note is that the inner loop is not starting at `i+1`, its starting at the `0`. When `A[i]` matches `A[l]`, we increment `count`. A number that appears an odd number of times will result in `count` becoming odd as well and we can return that number.

Answer (score 0):

You could count all values first and then get the value with an odd count.

```js
function getOddCount(array) {
    var value,
        count = {},
        k;

    for (value of array) count[value] = (count[value] || 0) + 1;
    for (k in count) if (count[k] % 2) return +k;
}

console.log(getOddCount([1, 1, 3, 1, 1]));
console.log(getOddCount([1, 1, 2, -2, 5, 2, 4, 4, -1, -2, 5]));
```

Answer (score 0):

A naive implementation would simply use an object to store the frequency of each element and then iterate over it at the end to find the element that appeared an odd amount of times.

```
function findOdd(arr) {
    const freq = {};
    for(const num of arr){
        freq[num] = (freq[num] || 0) + 1;
    }
    return +Object.keys(freq).find(num => freq[num] % 2 == 1);
}
```

A more efficient implementation could leverage the properties of the bitwise XOR (`^`), namely the fact that `a ^ a == 0` and that the operation is commutative and associative, leading to the solution of applying XOR on each element of the array to obtain the answer.

```
function findOdd(arr) {
    return arr.reduce((a,c)=>a ^ c, 0);
}
```