# How to group and count JSON data by multiple keys and for the last 30 days in Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, grouping

I'm displaying a chart and I need to know how I can pull the specific data I need from the array.

I'm trying to create a chart of a JSON array based on three columns. Source, Campaign, and Date. Group them, count them and then display them in the chart. It seems to be tricker than I thought as the results I'm getting are NaN and nothing close to what I'm trying to succeed.
This is the JSON array that I have

```
results = [{
    "utm-source": "direct",
    "utm-campaign": "nothing",
    "Date": "2019\/05\/10"
},
{
    "utm-source": "direct",
    "utm-campaign": "nothing",
    "Date": "2019\/08\/08"
},
{
    "utm-source": "direct",
    "utm-campaign": "nothing",
    "Date": "2019\/08\/09"
},
{
    "utm-source": "direct",
    "utm-campaign": "nothing",
    "Date": "2019\/08\/12"
},
{
    "utm-source": "google",
    "utm-campaign": "spring_sale",
    "Date": "2019\/08\/21"
},
{
    "utm-source": "facebook",
    "utm-campaign": "spring_sale",
    "Date": "2019\/08\/21"
},
{
    "utm-source": "email",
    "utm-campaign": "spring_sale",
    "Date": "2019\/08\/21"
}]
```

I have tried this but I'm nowhere near to the result I want:

```
var today = new Date();

var year = today.getFullYear();
var month = today.getMonth();
var date = today.getDate();

// build the last 30 days date array
var last30days = [];
for(var i=0; i<30; i++){
   var day = new Date(year, month, date - i);
   day = day.toISOString().split("T")[0].replace(/-/g,"/")
   last30days.push(day);
}
console.log(last30days);

var finalArray = [];
last30days.forEach(function(day,dayIndex){
   results.forEach(function(result,resultIndex) {
       var found = result.Date.indexOf(day);
       console.log(found);
       if(found == 0) {
           //console.log(result);
           finalArray[result.utm_source] += result.Lead_Source;
       } else {
           finalArray[result.utm_source] += "0";
       }
   });
});
```

The expected result should be this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbvMT.jpg 
Comparing this array to another array that has the last 30 days and displaying returning the number of leads for direct nothing or facebook spring_sale and for the days that there were no leads to return 0 and display that to the chart for the equivalent campaign and source that is displaying only once.
Also, the expected array should be like this:

```
{
    "direct": {
        "nothing": {
            "2019/07/24" : "0",
            "2019/07/25" : "0",
            "2019/07/26" : "0",
            "2019/07/27" : "0",
            "2019/07/28" : "0",
            "2019/07/29" : "0",
            "2019/07/30" : "0",
            "2019/07/31" : "0",
            "2019/08/01" : "0",
            "2019/08/02" : "0",
            "2019/08/03" : "0",
            "2019/08/04" : "0",
            "2019/08/05" : "0",
            "2019/08/06" : "0",
            "2019/08/07" : "0",
            "2019/08/08" : "1",
            "2019/08/09" : "1",
            "2019/08/10" : "0",
            "2019/08/11" : "0",
            "2019/08/12" : "1",
            "2019/08/13" : "0",
            "2019/08/14" : "0",
            "2019/08/15" : "0",
            "2019/08/16" : "0",
            "2019/08/17" : "0",
            "2019/08/18" : "0",
            "2019/08/19" : "0",
            "2019/08/20" : "0",
            "2019/08/21" : "0",
            "2019/08/22" : "0"
        }
    },
    "google":{
        "spring_sale": {
            "2019/07/24" : "0",
            "2019/07/25" : "0",
            "2019/07/26" : "0",
            "2019/07/27" : "0",
            "2019/07/28" : "0",
            "2019/07/29" : "0",
            "2019/07/30" : "0",
            "2019/07/31" : "0",
            "2019/08/01" : "0",
            "2019/08/02" : "0",
            "2019/08/03" : "0",
            "2019/08/04" : "0",
            "2019/08/05" : "0",
            "2019/08/06" : "0",
            "2019/08/07" : "0",
            "2019/08/08" : "0",
            "2019/08/09" : "0",
            "2019/08/10" : "0",
            "2019/08/11" : "0",
            "2019/08/12" : "0",
            "2019/08/13" : "0",
            "2019/08/14" : "0",
            "2019/08/15" : "0",
            "2019/08/16" : "0",
            "2019/08/17" : "0",
            "2019/08/18" : "0",
            "2019/08/19" : "0",
            "2019/08/20" : "0",
            "2019/08/21" : "1",
            "2019/08/22" : "0"
        }
    },
    "facebook":{
        "spring_sale": {
            "2019/07/24" : "0",
            "2019/07/25" : "0",
            "2019/07/26" : "0",
            "2019/07/27" : "0",
            "2019/07/28" : "0",
            "2019/07/29" : "0",
            "2019/07/30" : "0",
            "2019/07/31" : "0",
            "2019/08/01" : "0",
            "2019/08/02" : "0",
            "2019/08/03" : "0",
            "2019/08/04" : "0",
            "2019/08/05" : "0",
            "2019/08/06" : "0",
            "2019/08/07" : "0",
            "2019/08/08" : "0",
            "2019/08/09" : "0",
            "2019/08/10" : "0",
            "2019/08/11" : "0",
            "2019/08/12" : "0",
            "2019/08/13" : "0",
            "2019/08/14" : "0",
            "2019/08/15" : "0",
            "2019/08/16" : "0",
            "2019/08/17" : "0",
            "2019/08/18" : "0",
            "2019/08/19" : "0",
            "2019/08/20" : "0",
            "2019/08/21" : "1",
            "2019/08/22" : "0"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the code that you attempted along with the expected output array.

Comment: Sorry just added it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to group by `utm-source` you could do

```
const counts = {};
results.forEach(r => {
  counts[r["utm-source"]] = (counts[r["utm-source"]] || 0) + 1;
});
```

Output would look like

```
{ direct: 4, google: 1, facebook: 1, email: 1 }
```

Similar to [How to count duplicate value in an array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395257/how-to-count-duplicate-value-in-an-array-in-javascript), but with object instead of string arrays