# Count duplicate value from array into array of object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

Currently, I got an array like that:

```
 uniqueCount = [a,a,b,c,d,a,a];
```

How can I count how many a,b,c are there in the array? I want to have a result like with format of array of object:

```
[{key: "a", count: 4}
 {key: "b", count: 1}
 {key: "c", count: 1}
 {key: "d", count: 1}]
```

Mycode :

```
var current = null;
var count = 0;
 for (var i = 0; i < uniqueCount .length; i++) {
    if (uniqueCount [i] != current) {
      if (count > 0) {
        result.push({
          key: current,
          count: count
        });
      }
      current = uniqueCount [i];
      count = 1;
    } else {
      count++;
    }
  }
  if (count > 0) {
    result.push({
      key: current,
      count: count
    });
  }
```

But the result:

```
[{key: "a", count: 2}
 {key: "b", count: 1}
 {key: "c", count: 1}
 {key: "d", count: 1}
 {key: "a", count: 2}]
```

Thanks you .

Comment: Any efforts so far ? please post the code you have written so far

Comment: I've seen this question at least twice already within the last two days, every time with the quotes missing around the original array's elements. I wonder why...

Comment: This looks like an interview question...

Comment: @ASDFGerte - good to know... that's suspicious...

Comment: @TheSharpieOne or school assignment

Comment: hm, even the ones from 2013 don't have the quotes, so i think it's just something that happens... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395257/how-to-count-duplicate-value-in-an-array-in-javascript - the related posts i found in my history are now all deleted questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First count the character number of occurrence in `uniqueCount` array. Then make the resulting array of object using `map` as below

```js
var uniqueCount = ['a','a','b','c','d','a','a'];
var duplicateCount = {};
uniqueCount.forEach(e => duplicateCount[e] = duplicateCount[e] ? duplicateCount[e] + 1 : 1);
var result = Object.keys(duplicateCount).map(e => {return {key:e, count:duplicateCount[e]}});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Reduce the array to a Map, and then use `Array.from()` to convert to an array of objects:

```js
const array = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'a']

const count = Array.from(
  array.reduce((r, c) => r.set(c, (r.get(c) || 0) + 1), new Map()), 
  (([key, count]) => ({ key, count }))
)

console.log(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to apply condition properly, Check this snippet, First, we find in array by its name `f.key === m`. If found then increase it to 1 (`uniqueArray[index].count += 1`) else add into object with count 1.

```js
const array = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'a'];

const uniqueArray = [];
array.forEach((m) => {
  const obj = { key: m, count: 1 };
  const index = uniqueArray.findIndex((f) => { return f.key === m; });
  index === -1 ? uniqueArray.push(obj) : uniqueArray[index].count += 1;
});


console.log(uniqueArray)
```

Comment: @CườngBờm Welcome!

Comment: @CườngBờm I recommended you to answer a question which you know.

Answer (score 0):

```
    uniqueCount = ["a","a","b","c","d","a","a"]
    count = {}
    uniqueCount.forEach(x => {
       if(count[x]) {
           count[x] += 1
       }
        else {
           count[x] = 1
        }
    })
    const result = Object.keys(count).map(x => { return {key:x, count:count[x]}})
    console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `lodash` to work with complicated data transformation like your goal:

```
console.log(
  _.chain(uniqueCount)
  .groupBy()
  .map((value, key) => ({ key: key, count: value.length}))
  .value()
);
```

Lodash document: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15

Comment: Thanks you for your support