# Store first matched element in array for each in other array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects which contain addresses. I need to perform the following:

- Extract each postcode from address values.
- Find unique postcodes and store amount of duplicates.
- Store the first address for each unique postcode in a new array along with the number of duplicates.

Here is my current code.

```js
const json = [
  { "id": "10093729341", "address": "1 Alpha Road CF14 6AA" },
  { "id": "10024750520", "address": "2 Alpha Road CF14 6AA" },
  { "id": "10025738368", "address": "3 Alpha Road CF14 6AF" },
  { "id": "10025738368", "address": "4 Alpha Road CF14 6AF" },
  { "id": "10025738368", "address": "4 Alpha Road CF14 6AB" }
]

let allPostcodes = [];

json.forEach(address => {
  const fullAddresses = address.address;
  const postcodes = fullAddresses.split(",").map(s => s.trim().match(/([A-Za-z]{1,2}\d{1,2})(\s?(\d?\w{2}))?/)).filter(e => e)[0][0]
  allPostcodes.push(postcodes);
});

const uniquePostcodes = [...new Set(allPostcodes)];

uniquePostcodes.forEach(postcode => {
  const addresses = json.find(address => address.address.indexOf(postcode));
  console.log(addresses.address);
});
```

The final part above stops at the first match but for the first postcode only. I thought that in a loop it would work but it doesn't.

My desired outcome would be this:

```
const array = [
  {
    "address": "1 Alpha Road CF14 6AA",
    "count": 2,
    "postcode": "CF14 6AA"
  },
  {
    "address": "3 Alpha Road CF14 6AF",
    "count": 2,
    "postcode": "CF14 6AF"

  },
  {
    "address": "4 Alpha Road CF14 6AB",
    "count": 1,
    "postcode": "CF14 6AB"

  }
]
```

Comment: do you have an example of the wanted result?

Comment: I've added the update! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your current solution isn't working is due to the line:

```
const addresses = json.find(address => address.address.indexOf(postcode));
```

You return the `indexOf` result which is `-1` if the substring can't be found. `-1` is considdered truthy, which in turn signals `find` the the value is found. Changing this line to the following fixes your current code.

```
const addresses = json.find(address => address.address.indexOf(postcode) >= 0);
// or
const addresses = json.find(address => address.address.includes(postcode));
```

With the above being said, I'd personally would go for a different solution.

You can achieve the desired output by first grouping the addresses based upon postcode. Then build your output array using those groups.

```js
const json = [
  { "id": "10093729341", "address": "1 Alpha Road CF14 6AA" },
  { "id": "10024750520", "address": "2 Alpha Road CF14 6AA" },
  { "id": "10025738368", "address": "3 Alpha Road CF14 6AF" },
  { "id": "10025738368", "address": "4 Alpha Road CF14 6AF" },
  { "id": "10025738368", "address": "4 Alpha Road CF14 6AB" }
];

// Group addresses by postcode.
const postcodeRegex = /([A-Za-z]{1,2}\d{1,2})(\s?(\d?\w{2}))?/;
const addressesByPostcode = new Map();

json.forEach(address => {
  const postcode = address.address.match(postcodeRegex);
  
  if (!addressesByPostcode.has(postcode[0]))
    addressesByPostcode.set(postcode[0], []);
  addressesByPostcode.get(postcode[0]).push(address);
});

// Build output array.
const array = Array.from(addressesByPostcode)
                   .map(([postcode, addresses]) => ({
                     address:  addresses[0].address,
                     count:    addresses.length,
                     postcode: postcode,
                   }));

// Display result.
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

const postcodes = fullAddresses.split(",").
The split method will not work. You shouldn't use a comma inside the parenthesis because you don't have one In your address values. Use space instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think `find` method, need to be `find(address => address.address.indexOf(postcode) > -1` (make sure return boolean value)

Changed way to get the pincodoe, Assumed it is last one after split. (you can change it, But the main issue may be above)

```js
const json = [
  {
    id: "10093729341",
    address: "1 Alpha Road CF14 6AA"
  },
  {
    id: "10024750520",
    address: "2 Alpha Road CF14 6AA"
  },
  {
    id: "10025738368",
    address: "3 Alpha Road CF14 6AF"
  },
  {
    id: "10025738368",
    address: "4 Alpha Road CF14 6AF"
  },
  {
    id: "10025738368",
    address: "4 Alpha Road CF14 6AB"
  }
];

const codes = {};

json.forEach(({ address }) => {
  const postcode = address
    .split(" ")
    .slice(-2)
    .join(" ");
  codes[postcode] =
    postcode in codes
      ? { ...codes[postcode], count: codes[postcode].count + 1 }
      : { address, count: 1, postcode };
});

console.log(Object.values(codes));
```

Comment: Thanks. This works great. I have updated my code to show what the outcome is that I need.

Comment: @MattSimon, Glad to hear. I just updated the answer to have required output.

Answer (score 0):

You can improve the function of finding the postcode, but the rest remains the same.

```js
const json = [
            {
                "id": "10093729341",
                "address": "1 Alpha Road CF14 6AA"
            },
            {
                "id": "10024750520",
                "address": "2 Alpha Road CF14 6AA"
            },
            {
                "id": "10025738368",
                "address": "3 Alpha Road CF14 6AF"
            },
            {
                "id": "10025738368",
                "address": "4 Alpha Road CF14 6AF"
            },
            {
                "id": "10025738368",
                "address": "4 Alpha Road CF14 6AB"
            }
        ]


/*
 * You can (and should) improve this later
 */
const getPostCode = address => address.split(" ").slice(3, 5).join(" ");


let r = json.reduce((res, o) => {
  // Find the post code 
  let postCode = getPostCode(o.address);
  // Find if the post code exists
  let pCodeExists = res.findIndex(add => add.postCode.indexOf(postCode) > -1);  
  // If the address exsits, increase the count
  if (pCodeExists > 0) {
    res[pCodeExists]['count']++; 
  // Otherwise, add a new entity
  } else {
    res.push({
      address: o.address,
      count: 1,
      postCode
    });
  }
  
  return res;

}, []);

console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can help you...
In 3 lines.

[How to count duplicate value in an array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395257/how-to-count-duplicate-value-in-an-array-in-javascript)

```
var counts = {};
your_array.forEach(function(x) { counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0)+1; });
concole.log(counts);
```

```js
const json = [
            {
                "id": "10093729341",
                "address": "1 Alpha Road CF14 6AA"
            },
            {
                "id": "10024750520",
                "address": "2 Alpha Road CF14 6AA"
            },
            {
                "id": "10024750520",
                "address": "2 Alpha Road CF14 6AA"
            },
            {
                "id": "10025738368",
                "address": "3 Alpha Road CF14 6AF"
            },
            {
                "id": "10025738368",
                "address": "4 Alpha Road CF14 6AF"
            },
            {
                "id": "10025738368",
                "address": "4 Alpha Road CF14 6AB"
            }
        ]

let allPostcodes = [];
json.forEach(address => {
  const fullAddresses = address.address;
  const postcodes = fullAddresses.split(",").map(s => s.trim().match(/([A-Za-z]{1,2}\d{1,2})(\s?(\d?\w{2}))?/)).filter(e => e)[0][0]
  allPostcodes.push(postcodes);

});


var counts = {};
allPostcodes.forEach(function(x) { counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0)+1; });
console.log(counts);
```