# Javascript group a JSON object by two properties and count

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ecmascript-6, grouping

I have a JSON object like this:

```
long_array =    
[
{"location":"Kirrawee","identity_long":"student"},
{"location":"Kirrawee","identity_long":"visitor"},
{"location":"Kirrawee","identity_long":"visitor"},
{"location":"Kirrawee","identity_long":"worker"},
{"location":"Sutherland","identity_long":"student"},
{"location":"Sutherland","identity_long":"resident"},
{"location":"Sutherland","identity_long":"worker"},
{"location":"Sutherland","identity_long":"resident"},
{"location":"Miranda","identity_long":"resident"},
{"location":"Miranda","identity_long":"worker"},
{"location":"Miranda","identity_long":"student"},
{"location":"Miranda","identity_long":""},
{"location":"Miranda","identity_long":"worker"},
{"location":"Miranda","identity_long":"resident"}
];
```

What I want to achieve is an object like the following:

```
grouped_and_counted_location_and_identity =
[
{"location":"Kirrawee","identity":"student","count":1},
{"location":"Kirrawee","identity":"visitor","count":2},
{"location":"Kirrawee","identity":"worker","count":1},
{"location":"Sutherland","identity":"student","count":1},
{"location":"Sutherland","identity":"resident","count":2},
{"location":"Sutherland","identity":"worker","count":1},
{"location":"Miranda","identity":"resident","count":2},
{"location":"Miranda","identity":"worker","count":2},
{"location":"Miranda","identity":"student","count":1}
];
```

I find this extremely easy to achieve in the R language, where I would do this like:

```
long_array %>%
    group_by(location, identity_long) %>%
    summarise(n = n())
```

Or even just

```
long_array %>%
    count(location, identity_long)
```

But how can I achieve this in javascript?

I just want to group the JSON object by two properties and count the number of identical occurrences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use library such as lodash and use it's group by function to do this easy way, bit time consuming way would be to implement your own group by function.

```js
let long_array = [{
    "location": "Kirrawee",
    "identity_long": "student"
  },
  {
    "location": "Kirrawee",
    "identity_long": "visitor"
  },
  {
    "location": "Kirrawee",
    "identity_long": "visitor"
  },
  {
    "location": "Kirrawee",
    "identity_long": "worker"
  },
  {
    "location": "Sutherland",
    "identity_long": "student"
  },
  {
    "location": "Sutherland",
    "identity_long": "resident"
  },
  {
    "location": "Sutherland",
    "identity_long": "worker"
  },
  {
    "location": "Sutherland",
    "identity_long": "resident"
  },
  {
    "location": "Miranda",
    "identity_long": "resident"
  },
  {
    "location": "Miranda",
    "identity_long": "worker"
  },
  {
    "location": "Miranda",
    "identity_long": "student"
  },
  {
    "location": "Miranda",
    "identity_long": ""
  },
  {
    "location": "Miranda",
    "identity_long": "worker"
  },
  {
    "location": "Miranda",
    "identity_long": "resident"
  }
];

function addItemCounts(items, groupByKeys) {
  var groups = _.groupBy(long_array, obj => {
    return groupByKeys.map(key => obj[key]).join('-');
  });

  return _.map(groups, g => ({
    ...g[0],
    count: g.length
  }));
}

console.log(addItemCounts(long_array, ['identity_long', 'location']));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I noticed the output has a similar issue to Aman Sharmas answer, where if something has a count of 2, it appears twice in the output instead of once?

Comment: @DavideLorino I just updated it, if you take a look.

Answer (score 3):

create a set of unique values of array  and compair it with all values present in `long_array` and count the same values and save it in new array

```js
const long_array = [{
    "location": "Kirrawee",
    "identity_long": "student"
  },
  {
    "location": "Kirrawee",
    "identity_long": "visitor"
  },
  {
    "location": "Kirrawee",
    "identity_long": "visitor"
  },
  {
    "location": "Kirrawee",
    "identity_long": "worker"
  },
  {
    "location": "Sutherland",
    "identity_long": "student"
  },
  {
    "location": "Sutherland",
    "identity_long": "resident"
  },
  {
    "location": "Sutherland",
    "identity_long": "worker"
  },
  {
    "location": "Sutherland",
    "identity_long": "resident"
  },
  {
    "location": "Miranda",
    "identity_long": "resident"
  },
  {
    "location": "Miranda",
    "identity_long": "worker"
  },
  {
    "location": "Miranda",
    "identity_long": "student"
  },
  {
    "location": "Miranda",
    "identity_long": ""
  },
  {
    "location": "Miranda",
    "identity_long": "worker"
  },
  {
    "location": "Miranda",
    "identity_long": "resident"
  }
];
const unique_values = [...new Map(long_array.map(obj => [JSON.stringify(obj), obj])).values()]; // this will remove duplicate values from long_array
const result = unique_values.map((val) => { // iterate in unique_values
  let count = 0;
  long_array.forEach((item) => {
    item.location == val.location && item.identity_long === val.identity_long && count++
  }); //iterate in long_array and count same values
  return { ...val,
    count: count
  }
})
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is excellent - is there any chance you or anyone else could comment what is going on here?

Comment: Just one thing I noticed with this solution... if something has a count of 2, it seems to appear twice in the `result` object

Comment: Hi updated the answer check now, sorry for late reply

Comment: this should have been the accepted answer since it does NOT uses any library (lodash) and provide a complete native JS solution to get the results.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with time complexity of `O(n*logn)` and space complexity of `O(n)`

```js
let long_array =
  [
    { "location": "Kirrawee", "identity_long": "student" },
    { "location": "Kirrawee", "identity_long": "visitor" },
    { "location": "Kirrawee", "identity_long": "visitor" },
    { "location": "Kirrawee", "identity_long": "worker" },
    { "location": "Sutherland", "identity_long": "student" },
    { "location": "Sutherland", "identity_long": "resident" },
    { "location": "Sutherland", "identity_long": "worker" },
    { "location": "Sutherland", "identity_long": "resident" },
    { "location": "Miranda", "identity_long": "resident" },
    { "location": "Miranda", "identity_long": "worker" },
    { "location": "Miranda", "identity_long": "student" },
    { "location": "Miranda", "identity_long": "" },
    { "location": "Miranda", "identity_long": "worker" },
    { "location": "Miranda", "identity_long": "resident" }
  ];

// create map
let map = new Map()

for (let i = 0; i < long_array.length; i++) {
  const s = JSON.stringify(long_array[i])

  if (!map.has(s)) {
    // if the map does not contain the object already
    // i.e. its first occurrence
    map.set(s, {
      location: long_array[i].location,
      identity: long_array[i].identity_long,
      count: 1,
    })
  } else {
    // if it no first occurrence
    // increase the count straight way
    map.get(s).count++
  }
}

const result = Array.from(map.values())
console.log(result)
```

Comment: you forgot the complexity of `map.has()` which is O(logn) so your complexity is O(nLogn)

Comment: Thanx @AbishekKumar. Updated

Answer (score 1):

This is what i've managed to come up with, now that i saw the other answers it's very complicated, but i think it works:

```
const grouped_and_counted_location_and_identity = [];

const sort = () => {
  long_array.forEach((el) => {
    let count = 0;
    for (let i = long_array.indexOf(el); i < long_array.length; i++) {
      if (
        el.location == long_array[i].location &&
        el.identity_long == long_array[i].identity_long
      ) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    el.count = count;
    if (
      !grouped_and_counted_location_and_identity.some(
        (elem) =>
          elem.location == el.location && elem.identity_long == el.identity_long
      )
    ) {
      grouped_and_counted_location_and_identity.push(el);
    }
  });
};

sort();

console.log(grouped_and_counted_location_and_identity);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this would be to convert the objects to strings (using something like [JSON.stringify](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp)). Since comparing objects in JavaScript compares the instance, and not the fields/values, converting to strings would make it easier to identify duplicates. You could then do [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19395302/12684394) to get a count of the duplicates! Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a mapping of counts based on a string containing the `location` and the `identity_long`:

   ```js
   { Kirrawee-student: 1, ... }
   ```
2. Map through each entry and transform it to the desired structure.

```js
const long_array = [
  { "location": "Kirrawee", "identity_long": "student" },
  { "location": "Kirrawee", "identity_long": "visitor" },
  { "location": "Kirrawee", "identity_long": "visitor" },
  { "location": "Kirrawee", "identity_long": "worker" },
  { "location": "Sutherland", "identity_long": "student" },
  { "location": "Sutherland", "identity_long": "resident" },
  { "location": "Sutherland", "identity_long": "worker" },
  { "location": "Sutherland", "identity_long": "resident" },
  { "location": "Miranda", "identity_long": "resident" },
  { "location": "Miranda", "identity_long": "worker" },
  { "location": "Miranda", "identity_long": "student" },
  { "location": "Miranda", "identity_long": "" },
  { "location": "Miranda", "identity_long": "worker" },
  { "location": "Miranda", "identity_long": "resident" }
];

const countsMap = _.countBy(long_array, e => `${e.location}-${e.identity_long}`);
const longArrayWithCount = Object.entries(countsMap).map(([group, count]) => {
 const [location, identity_long] = group.split('-');

 return { location, identity_long, count };
});

console.log(longArrayWithCount);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) along with [`Optional Chaining`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

```js
let long_array = [{location:'Kirrawee',identity_long:'student'},{location:'Kirrawee',identity_long:'visitor'},{location:'Kirrawee',identity_long:'visitor'},{location:'Kirrawee',identity_long:'worker'},{location:'Sutherland',identity_long:'student'},{location:'Sutherland',identity_long:'resident'},{location:'Sutherland',identity_long:'worker'},{location:'Sutherland',identity_long:'resident'},{location:'Miranda',identity_long:'resident'},{location:'Miranda',identity_long:'worker'},{location:'Miranda',identity_long:'student'},{location:'Miranda',identity_long:''},{location:'Miranda',identity_long:'worker'},{location:'Miranda',identity_long:'resident'}];

const formatData = (data) => {
  const finalRes = data.reduce((res, {location, identity_long}) => {
  //Formatting a composite key using `location` and `identity_long`
    let key = `${location}_${identity_long}`;
    res[key] = {
      ...res[key],
      location,
      identity: identity_long,
      //Accessing the count form the result/accumulator if exists and if not assigning `0` and updating by 1
      count: (res[key]?.count || 0) + 1
    }
    return res;
  }, {});
  //Finally returning the values of the object 
  return Object.values(finalRes)
}

console.log(formatData(long_array))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```