# counting duplicates from a passed in string

Tags: javascript

so i had this problem on codewars, where i have to find same letters in a passed in string and shall return the letters that are twice or more often inside that string. Here is my attempt which threw out an error:

```
function duplicateCount(text){
  text.split('')
  for(var i = 0, i < text.length, i++) {
    for(var j = 1, j < text.length + 1, j++)
      if(text[j] = text[i]) {
        return text[i]
      }
    else return
  }
  //...
}
```

i have very little expierience so dont be to harsh lmao

Comment: first of all. Search for the `for` loop syntax. Second, search for difference between assignment `=` and comparison `==` or `===` . And start from that. You can also search for your specific problem ' find duplicate letters in string ' and i am sure you will find dozens of answers online.

Comment: 1. Your `j` index is hard-coded to 1, it should be set to `i + 1`, 2. Bound checking for 2nd for loop should be `j < text.length` 3. Use the boolean operator `==` to make comparison in the if statement

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to count duplicate value in an array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395257/how-to-count-duplicate-value-in-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You can try converting the string array to a set. Since sets can't have duplicates, you will get the difference in size. Therefore, the count.

```
const countDuplicates = (str) => {
    const arr = str.split(''); 
    const arrSet = new Set(arr);
    return arr.length - arrSet.size 
}

console.log(countDuplicates('abcdac')
```

Output: 2

Edit: I missed the part where you asked about returning the duplicate characters. For that:

```
const getDuplicateChars = (str) => { 

const arr = str.split('');
const duplicateChars = [];
const sortedArr = [...arr].sort();

sortedArr.forEach((elem, index) => {
    if(sortedArr[index+1] === elem) {
        duplicateChars.push(elem);
    }
});
return duplicateChars;
}

let duplicateChars = getDuplicateChars('abcdac');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a two ways to determine which characters of a string occur twice or more in that string.

Learn more:

- [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)
- [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```js
const str = "I_am_a_string_with_probably_duplicate_characters";
console.log(JSON.stringify(duplicateCount(str)));
console.log(duplicateCountLoop(str).join("; "));

// using a reducer/filter
function duplicateCount(text){
  // determine the frequencies of each character in the string
  const charFrequencies = text.split('')
    .reduce( (acc, chr) => ({...acc, [chr]: (acc[chr] || 0) + 1}), {});
  // filter the result for character with more than 1 ocurrences  
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(charFrequencies)
    .filter( ([key, value]) => value > 1 )
  );
}

// in a loop
function duplicateCountLoop(text){
  // determine the frequencies of each character in the string
  const textIterable = text.split('');
  let characterFrequencies = {};
  for (let chr of textIterable) {
    characterFrequencies[chr] = (characterFrequencies[chr] || 0) + 1;
  }
  let result = [];
  for (freq in characterFrequencies) {
    if (characterFrequencies[freq] > 1) {
      result.push(`${freq}: ${characterFrequencies[freq]}`);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the title, your question body and the code says you want letters that appear more than once.

Your method have some issues.

`text.split('')` won't alter original array. It simply returns an array.

use `;` instead of `,` in `for` loop.

Here's an alternative method in ES6.

1. convert string to lowercase to match all characters regardless of case. Remove `.toLowerCase()` if you want to match case.
2. Split the string to array
3. Use filter with conditition `(x,y) => str.indexOf(x) != y)` to get duplicate elements.
4. Since the resulting array may have duplicate elements and you want only repeating elements, we need to remove duplicates form array.
5. Use filter with `conditition (x,y) => arr.indexOf(x) == y)` to get non duplicate elements.
6. Here, I used IIFE to pass the first filtered array to second filter function and return it directly.
7. You can use `Set` instead of second filter, if you want.

```js
duplicateFind = (str) => {
  str = str.toLowerCase().split('');
  return ((arr) => arr.filter((x, y) => arr.indexOf(x) == y))(str.filter((x, y) => str.indexOf(x) != y))
}
console.log("Letters appearing more than once in string 'Hello there'");
console.log(duplicateFind("Hello there"));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
let duplicate=text.split('').filter((item, index) => text.split('').indexOf(item) != index)
```