# Trying to fetch id from a API from another API in react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api

I am trying to fetch data from another fetched data by id, then display them together in a card using react hooks.  I am getting an empty array error in the console.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also not sure if I am storing the data correctly in state.

```
const CardContainer = () => {
  const [work, setWork] = useState([]);
  const [work2, setWork2] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/work_orders")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data.orders);
        data.orders.map((order) => {
          console.log(order.workerId);
          fetch(
            `https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/workers/${order.workerId}`
          )
            .then((res) => res)
            .then((data) => setWork2(data));
        });
      });
  }, []);
  console.log(work);
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Cards</h2>
      {work.map((items, index) => (
        <CardUI key={index} props={items} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image]

Comment: I know next to nothing about React, but this is probably another duplicate of the good old [How do I return a response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: 1. First this you are assigning data in `work2` ( `setWork2(data)`), but you are using `work` while displaying data.

2. `console.log(work);` You are printing data outside the then but it won't print. 

3. `data.orders.map` You are iterating on data.orders and inside that iteation you are calling an API. So here you have to push resulted data in an array. Setting them directly like `setWork(data)` replaces the old data.

Comment: how can I show both work id and orders ids in one card? I can only seem to get workers id in the cards.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
fetch('https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/work_orders')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
        const respones = data.orders.map((order) =>
            fetch(`https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/workers/${order.workerId}`).then((res) => res.json()),
        );

        Promise.all(respones).then((fetchedOrders) => {
            setWork2(fetchedOrders);
        });
    });
```

If you have more specific question please ask in the comment

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to display orders that match the ids of workers together on a card. Is it possible to map matching order workerIds to worker id on a card?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `map` to create a new array of promises you should use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait until they've all either been resolved or been rejected. Then you can `map` over that JSON, parse it, and add it to state.

```js
fetch('https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/work_orders')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    const orders = data.orders.map(order => {
      fetch(`https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/workers/${order.workerId}`)
    });
    Promise.all(orders).then(data => {
      setWork2(data.map(data => JSON.parse(el));
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to display orders that match the ids of workers together on a card. Is it possible to map matching order workerIds to worker id on a card?

Answer (score 0):

```
const CardContainer = () => {

const [work, setWork] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/work_orders')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        const respones = data.orders.map((order) =>
          fetch(`https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/workers/${order.workerId}`).then((res) => res.json()),
        );
        Promise.all(respones).then((fetchedOrders) => {
          setWork(fetchedOrders);
          setIsLoading(false)
        });
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    isLoading ? <div>Loading</div> : <div>
      <h2>Cards</h2>
      {work.map((item, index) => (
        <div key={index} props={item}>{item.worker.companyName} </div>
      ))}
    </div>

  )
}
```

- i have added loading and showing company name in card
  **output**
  [image]

Comment: Hi @AvaniBataviya , Thank you.  I am trying to display orders that match the ids of workers together on a card.  Is it possible to map matching order workerIds to worker id on a card?

Comment: yes you can do.. find same id from work array and then print data of it. Below link will useful to you.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395257/how-to-count-duplicate-value-in-an-array-in-javascript?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: the only thing I can print and get is the workers id, I can not get any orders id. I also need to print out orders ids

Comment: are you saying that I should use a for loop?