# Number of occurrences in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, find-occurrences

Is it possible to have the number of occurrences of each value in an array?

For example :

```
items = ["pineapple", "apples", "tomatoes", "water", "apples","tomatoes"];
```

I want to display :

> pineapple appears 1 time, apples appears 2 times etc..

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12749200/how-to-count-array-elements-by-each-element-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count array elements by each element in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12749200/how-to-count-array-elements-by-each-element-in-javascript)

Comment: This has nothing to do with Angular. It's plain old JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code

```
const items = ["pineapple", "apples", "tomatoes", "water", "apples","tomatoes"];
items.reduce((counts, curr) => (counts[curr] = ++counts[curr] || 1, counts), {});
```

Comment: This will count values of `1` and `"1"` as being identical.