# Remove duplicates from array, convert to array of objects and add duplicate count property

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of strings:

```
var array = ['bob', 'charlie', 'bob', 'bob'];
```

that I want to remove duplicates from, and then I'd like to convert it to an array of objects whilst adding a duplicate count property.

This is what I want to achieve:

```
var filteredData = [{ name: 'bob', count: 3}, { name: 'charlie', count: 1}];
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count Matching values in Array of Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228362/how-to-count-matching-values-in-array-of-javascript)

Comment: not an exact duplicate, but answer will be a slightly modified version of the answer

Answer (score 3):

***Ecmascript5*** solution using [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function:

```js
var arr = ['bob', 'charlie', 'bob', 'bob'],
    counts = arr.reduce(function(r,s){
        (!r[s])? r[s] = {name: s, count: 1} : r[s]['count']+=1;
        return r;
    }, {}),
    result = Object.keys(counts).map(function(k){ return counts[k]; });
    
console.log(result);
```

---

***Ecmascript6*** version (with [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) function):

```js
var arr = ['bob', 'charlie', 'bob', 'bob'],
    result = Object.values(arr.reduce((r,s) => {
        (!r[s])? r[s] = {name: s, count: 1} : r[s]['count']+=1;
        return r;
    }, {}));
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const array = ['bob', 'charlie', 'bob', 'bob']; 

const result = [...array.reduce((map, name) => {
  const current = map.get(name) || { name, count: 0 };
  
  current.count++;

  return map.set(name, current);
}, new Map()).values()];

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some straightforward usage of [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const data = ['bob', 'charlie', 'bob', 'bob']

const result = data.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
  const index = prev.findIndex(el => el.name === curr)

  if (index !== -1) {
    prev[index].count += 1
  } else {
    prev.push({ name: curr, count: 1 })
  }

  return prev
}, [])

console.log(result)
```